# Can i propagate applications insight clientside telemetry through the webserver?

Tags: asp.net, azure, azure-application-insights

I realize a similar question has been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41982437/can-i-funnel-application-insight-browser-telemetry-through-a-custom-domain). Although it talks specifically of a custom domain, whereas i would want to send the data from the clients to the webserver where the serverside SDK is running and then send it from there. Is there any way to do this? We have PCs which will be stripped of direct internet access, however the webserver will not.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer from @John Gardner applies here - you need:
1. Send data from your app to your server/web server
2. In web server send data to Application Insights